# Any Database update refreshes React + Django app

Tags: django, reactjs

I'm currently a beginner with React and I'm currently building a React application that is run on top of Django Framework. My strategy is that I have a single Django template where I attach the whole React application. Basically in my `urls.py` in Django, I have a list of URLS for all my REST API's and a URL for the single template.

I have been stuck with this for quite sometime. There's this weird behavior where **any update I do with the database refreshes the website**, whether this update is through a form in React (even though I do `e.preventDefault()`) or doing an update in the Django built-in admin panel page (either Creating, Updating, or Deleting something).

I don't exactly know what to share with you (i.e. which part of my code) because I don't even know what the problem is in the first place, but I would be happy to comply to any of your requests. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is innate of React, everytime you change the React State, it triggers a re-render.
To stop this, you might want to see if your database updates are changing the react state and adjust accordingly.

Comment: I am aware that react re-renders for any react state change, but even the database update I do in a different page (from the Django built-in admin panel) triggers a refresh on the currently opened React page and even the changes I do in the database with the tables that aren't related to the currently opened React page triggers a refresh.

Comment: Isn't this something related to django then?

Comment: That is something I don't have any idea with as well, although I have tried Django before, but I have no prior experience with combining Django with React :/ I'm using webpack which I don't have a strong grasp also on what's going on. I just followed this guide on Github (https://github.com/mbrochh/django-reactjs-boilerplate) so perhaps the issue lies somewhere here?

Comment: I know some python but i don't know about Django..
Maybe someone else can help you with that part, i still think it's a React re-rendering that is being triggered, but it might be something innate to Django.

Comment: Okay no problem sir, thank you very much for taking the time to respond! Really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, sorry i couldn't be more helpful, wish you luck with this, it might be something trivial.